# getting null value in action from ajax call

Tags: hibernate, select, struts2, dojo, null

Getting **null value** from ajax call in action (**FirstList.java**)... first list is loading correctly.
Need help, i am new to struts2 and hibernate.

StudentRegistration.jsp

```
<%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1"
    pageEncoding="ISO-8859-1"%>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<%@taglib uri="/struts-tags" prefix="s"%>
<%@taglib uri="/struts-dojo-tags" prefix="sx"%>

<html>
<head>
    <sx:head />
    <title>Student Registration</title>
</head>

<script>
function show_details() {
dojo.event.topic.publish("show_detail");
}
</script>

<body>
    <s:form id="form1" name="form1" action="StudentRegister" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data" theme="simple">
    <s:hidden name="id" />
    <table border="0">
    ...

    <tr>
    <td><s:label value="Course " for="course" /></td>

    <td><s:select name="course" list="courseList" onchange="javascript:show_details();return false;" /></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
    <td colspan="2"><s:url id="durl" action="secload" /><sx:div showLoadingText="" id="details" href="%{durl}" listenTopics="show_detail"  formId="form1" ></sx:div></td>  
    </tr>

    <tr>
    <td align="center" colspan="2"><s:submit /></td>
    </tr>
    </table>
    </s:form>
</body>
</html>
```

Detail.jsp

```
<%@taglib uri="/struts-tags" prefix="s"%>
<%@taglib uri="/struts-dojo-tags" prefix="sx"%>
<table border="0" width=100%>
<s:if test="branchList != null">
<tr><td><s:select name="branch" list="branchList" label="Branch"></s:select></td></tr></s:if>
<s:if test="semList != null">  
<tr><td><s:select name="sem" list="semList" label="Semester" /></td></tr></s:if>
</table>
```

FirstList.java

```
package bharat;

    public class FirstList extends ActionSupport {
        private String course;
        private Map<Integer,Integer> semList=null;
        private Map<String, String> branchList=null;

        public String execute() throws Exception
        {
            populateTwo(getCourse());
            return SUCCESS;
        }

        public void populateTwo(String id1)
        {
                    // Get null value for id1
            System.out.println (id1);

            if(id1!=null&&!id1.equals(""))
            {
            semList=new HashMap<Integer,Integer>();
            branchList=new HashMap<String,String>();
            if (id1.equalsIgnoreCase("B.Tech.")||id1.equalsIgnoreCase("M.Tech.")) {  
                branchList.put("CSE","CSE");
                branchList.put("ECE","ECE");
                branchList.put("MAE","MAE");
                branchList.put("CHE","CHE");
                branchList.put("CVE","CVE");
                branchList.put("IT","IT");
                } else if (id1.equalsIgnoreCase("MCA")) {  
                    branchList.put("CS","CS");
                    branchList.put("EC","EC");
                    branchList.put("MA","MA");
                    branchList.put("CIV","CIV");
                    branchList.put("IT","IT");
                }
                else{branchList.put("None","None");}
            if (id1.equalsIgnoreCase("B.Tech.")||id1.equalsIgnoreCase("Bio.Tech.")) {  
            semList.put(1,1);  
            semList.put(2,2);  
            semList.put(3,3);  
            semList.put(4,4);  
            semList.put(5,5);
            semList.put(6,6);
            semList.put(7,7);
            semList.put(8,8);
            setSemList(semList);
            } else if (id1.equalsIgnoreCase("M.Tech.")) {  
                semList.put(1,1);  
                semList.put(2,2);  
                semList.put(3,3);  
                semList.put(4,4);
            } else {  
                semList.put(1,1);  
                semList.put(2,2);  
                semList.put(3,3);  
                semList.put(4,4);  
                semList.put(5,5);
                semList.put(6,6);
            }
            }
        }

        public String getCourse() {
            return course;
        }
        public void setCourse(String course) {
            this.course = course;
        }
        public Map<Integer,Integer> getSemList() {
            return (this.semList); 
        }
        public void setSemList(Map<Integer,Integer> semList) {
            this.semList = semList; 
        }
        public void setBranchList(Map<String, String> branchList) {
            this.branchList = branchList;
        }

        public Map<String, String> getBranchList() {
            return branchList;
        }
    }
```

Struts.xml

```
<!DOCTYPE struts PUBLIC
"-//Apache Software Foundation//DTD Struts Configuration 2.0//EN"
"http://struts.apache.org/dtds/struts-2.0.dtd">

<struts>
    <package name="default" extends="hibernate-default">
    ...
    <action name="StudentRegister" class="bharat.RegistrationAction">
          <interceptor-ref name="defaultStackHibernate">
        <param name="fileUpload.allowedTypes">image/png,image/gif,image/jpeg</param>
        </interceptor-ref>
        <result name="input">/jsp/StudentRegistration.jsp</result>
        <result name="success">/jsp/success2.jsp</result>
    </action>
    **<action name="linkStudentRegister" method="populateOne" class="bharat.RegistrationAction">
        <result name="success">/jsp/StudentRegistration.jsp</result>
    </action>
    <action name="secload" class="bharat.FirstList">
        <result name="success">/jsp/Detail.jsp</result>
    </action>**
    </package>
</struts>
```

web.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee" xmlns:web="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_2_5.xsd" xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_2_5.xsd" id="WebApp_ID" version="2.5">
  <display-name>CourseRegistrationModule</display-name>
  <filter>
        <filter-name>struts2</filter-name>
        <filter-class>
            org.apache.struts2.dispatcher.ng.filter.StrutsPrepareAndExecuteFilter</filter-class>
    </filter>
    <filter-mapping>
        <filter-name>struts2</filter-name>
        <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
    </filter-mapping>

    <welcome-file-list>
        <welcome-file>index.jsp</welcome-file>
    </welcome-file-list>
</web-app>
```

RegistrationAction.java

```
package bharat;

public class RegistrationAction extends ActionSupport implements ModelDriven<Register>,ServletRequestAware {

    private Register register = new Register();
    private RegisterDAO registerDAO = new RegisterDAOImpl();
    private HttpServletRequest servletRequest;
    private Map<String,String> courseList= null;

    public String populateOne()
    {
        System.out.println ("populateone");
        courseList=new HashMap<String,String>();
        courseList.put("B.Tech.","B.Tech.");
        courseList.put("M.Tech.","M.Tech.");
        courseList.put("MCA","MCA");
        courseList.put("Bio.Tech.","Bio.Tech.");
        return SUCCESS;
    }


    public Map<String,String> getCourseList() {
        return (this.courseList); 
    }
    public void setCourseList(Map<String,String> courseList) {
        this.courseList = courseList; 
    }

    @Override
    public Register getModel() {
        //TODO
        return register;
    }
    @Override 
    public void setServletRequest(HttpServletRequest servletRequest) {
        this.servletRequest = servletRequest;
    }

    public String execute() {

        ...
        return SUCCESS;
    }

    public Register getRegister() {
        return register;
    }

    public void setRegister(Register register) {
        this.register = register;
    }
}
```

Comment: What's being sent in the request? What makes the request? What's the Dojo "show_detail" topic hooked up to?

Comment: selected course is sent in the request in StudentRegistration.jsp.As i  have use onchange event on course select box and have corresponding dojo div with "listenTopic" attribute.

Comment: I *think* I see the logic--it would be *so* much easier to help if you didn't make people read and understand that much code and configuration first. *Way* too much unrelated code; you're asking about a single request.

Comment: The quickest way to help would be to put a minimally-failing example project and its Maven file on github; I don't see anything immediately wrong, but there's a lot to wade through so I could be missing something.

Comment: sorry,i am new to this thing and its my first question on any forum.http://www.fromdev.com/2008/07/struts-2-ajax-drop-down-example_6449.html i applied this code and its working fine if i don't use hibernate..

Comment: Then make sure devMode is turned on and you're logging at the debug level; the request where you're getting the null doesn't have anything to do with Hibernate, so the problem lies elsewhere.

Comment: devMode is turned on. Problem lies where in configuration files or in action class?

Answer (score 0):

finally, i get it correct by changing name of hidden tag to id1....